# Can't create Careers 2.0 profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, profile-page

I got the "Something terrible happened" message when trying to access my profile on Careers 2.0.

Specifically: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/cv/edit/48566

As a side note, great use of the Muppets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your profile was created, but it had some bad data due to a bug.  I've fixed the data, and the bug so you should be able to edit your profile normally now.  Sorry about that!

Comment: Excellent! Working!