# Problem logging into account on SO Careers

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

After receiving an invitation to SO Careers I have tried to create an account and login afterwards. Whenever I try to login, however, I get an error message ["Oops! Something Bad Happened!"](http://openid.stackauth.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/OpenId/Provider) that is not really useful in identifying the source of the problem. It seems to be a different issue than [other members report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83882/cannot-create-profile-on-careers).

**Update:** It seems other members experience similar problems, see e.g. [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87588/cant-create-careers-2-0-profile).

I have experienced the same problem on Firefox 4.0.1 (MacOS X 10.6.7, all latest patches installed) and Safari 5.0.5. The problem persists for more than a week now.

**Final update:** After a couple of iterations, the problem has been solved (although the source has not been fully determined).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, this should be resolved. Would you try again?

Comment: No, still the same behavior. Again, I tried it with Firefox and Safari in configurations as listed above. For Firefox I still had the OpenID login cookies active (which may have had some adverse effect), but on Safari I definitely started with "clean" cookies. The result is the same in both cases - the error message listed in my posting.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble. Would you send us a note at careers@stackoverflow.com and let us know what email address you are using to log on? Thanks.

Comment: Ok, done!